# How do I add IF ELSE to linux variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I have a variable in my script that displays the user:

```
OWNER=$(grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd|cut -f1 -d':')
```

Output will be something like:

```
joe
```

This is fine on a normal server where the os was installed & user was setup during the install.  I run into problems on a vps where there is no initial user. I would like to add to the variable IF blank then the output should be "root" but I don't know where to start..

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to check for return value of `grep` command?
If it returns `1` when use root as user, otherwise - `cut` its result and use it.

```
LINE="`grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd`"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && OWNER="`echo "$LINE"|cut -f1 -d":"`" || OWNER=root
```

Comment: You should quote both $USER and $LINE if you don't want weird expansion (e.g. $USER will always be echoed as having 1-space between word tokens and no leading or trailing spaces, regardless of however many it had from command output)

Comment: Thankyou, That worked perfectly..  Can the full expression be on one line or does it have to be on 2 lines?

Comment: @linuxnoob You can put `;` to the end of each line and join them together one-by-one. BTW Do you really need it? It will be harder to understand such line. Instead you can create a function for that purpose. It is much better than combining all the lines into one.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
[[ $OWNER == "" ]] && OWNER="root"
```

or

```
if [[ $OWNER == "" ]]; then
  OWNER="root"
fi
```

Comment: Thankyou, Is there a way to have this check all contained in the variable?  For example: `OWNER=$(grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd|cut -f1 -d':') [[ $OWNER == "" ]] && OWNER="root"`

Comment: Yes : OWNER=$((grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd || echo "root") | cut -f1 -d":")

Comment: @linuxnoob I like Imsteffan's suggestion. Alternatively you can just put a `;` after the `)` in your example.